# SignalR automatic reconnecting is taking around 2 mins before closed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, signalr, maui

My issue is that the reconnecting timeout to signalR is taking around 2 minutes before raising the closed event which wouldn't reflect back to the user
the default configuration is set on both client and backend which is odd for me since timeout configuration does not exceed 30 seconds I cant figure out the 2 minutes timeout reason could it be something related to iis

This is my code

```html
_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                                             .WithUrl(_url, options =>
                                                          { options.Headers.Add("User", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user)); })
                                             .ConfigureLogging((builder) => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug))
                                             .WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) })
                                             .Build();


  _hubConnection.Reconnecting += (e) =>
  {
      App.AlertSvc.ShowAlert("", "Connection lost attemting to reconnect...");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
  };

  _hubConnection.Reconnected += (e) =>
  {
      App.AlertSvc.ShowAlert("", "Connection established");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
  };

  _hubConnection.Closed += (e) =>
  {
      if (e != null)
      {
          // The connection was closed due to an exception
          App.AlertSvc.ShowAlert("", $"Connection closed. Reason: {e.Message}");

          App.AlertSvc.ShowAlert("", "Connection error, make sure you have an active internet connection!!");
      }

      return Task.CompletedTask;
  };
```

Comment: Is there a network issue causing a delay in the connection process? Check the server logs for any relevant details.